# Regex remove spaces after 2 letters

Tags: regex

What is the regex for no whitespaces after the first 2 letters? For example, the string starts with AB then is followed by an undetermined amount of numbers and/or letters but it cannot have any spaces.

```
(^[A][B][\S])
```

Comment: What platform is using this regex?

Comment: oops javascript but the first too leters are it must start with these specific letters not just any letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}\S+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/sRfUFYqmUmQTtJZe)

- `^` denotes the start of the line
- `[a-zA-Z]{2}` denotes exactly 2 letters
- `\S` any character besides white spaces
- `+` one or more.
- `$` denotes end of string.

please read more about [regex here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and use [debugexx.com](http://www.debuggex.com/) to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Python, so I'll just assume that.

`^\w\w\S*`

That's 2 word characters at the start of the line, followed by 0 or more non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what platform you're using, but you can try the following:

```
^[\d\w]{2}[^\s]*$
```

Should do the trick.
The `[\d\w]{2}` represents 2 letters or digits and then the `[^\s]` means no white space for zero or more characters afterwards.  The caret and dollar sign notation force this to happen at the beginning of the string.

EDIT:  Although the title of this question is remove white space your question seems to just ask for the regex for 2 letter/digit characters with no white space afterwards, which is what I answered.  If you are looking for how to make a lookahead ignore my answer.